# Dynamic Object call in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

I develop in codeigniter. My program'll automaticly create it database, so i create for every table a createScheme() method. I try to call all these method like this:

```
public function createDB()
{
    $tables = array('user', 'manufacturer', 'device');

    foreach ($tables as $i => $table) {
        $this->load->library($table);
        $this->{$table}::createScheme();
    }

}
```

This is create an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in
>   /var/www/clients/client0/web79/web/application/controllers/welcome.php
>   on line 22

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$this->{$table}->createScheme();
```

See also [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator)

Answer (score 2):

T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM is Hebrew, and it refers to PHP’s scope resolution operator (“::”). If you get this message, it means PHP sees a class name and expects you to access it with the scope resolution operator.

So createScheme() is not a static, but a normal class method.

Use

```
$this->{$table}->createScheme();
```

Comment: But my method is declareted like this: public static function createScheme()